# Eclipse doens't show intellisense drop down menu

Tags: eclipse

I installed the latest eclipse (Kepler), but it doesn't show the drop down menu like it used to ( for example when I used to type `System.out.` , normally a `println` would appear). Is there a setting I need to change to turn it on?

Comment: I believe you will have to check your templates or content assist. http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Select Window -> Preferences

2) Java -> Editor -> Content Assist. Under Auto-Activation, make sure that Enable Auto-Activation is selected.

3) Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced. Enusre that `Java Proposals` is checked under `Default Proposal Kinds`

Also, make sure that you have the Java source attached/linked:

1) Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path

2) Under Libraries tab, expand JRE System Library

3) Expand rt.jar and ensure that Source attachment is populated (src.zip)

**EDIT:**

Also, make sure you're in a "code" area (i.e. within a method or constructor), and not just any old place in the editor.  For example:

```
public class Test
{
  // Not ok here:
  System.out.

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Ok here:
    System.out.
  }
}
```

Comment: I looked into Source attachment, and it said (none), where should i find the src.zip file? thank you

Comment: It should be in the top level of the JDK installation.

Comment: From Preferences, look at Java -> Installed JREs. One or more will be listed, but only one will be checked.  This shows the Location of the install.

Comment: thank you splungebob, I've attached it, but the content assist still shows 'no default proposal'..

Comment: `No default proposal` typically is a result of it not understanding what you've typed BEFORE the dot. Possibly, you either misspelled something or a class type needs to be imported.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't have IntelliSense, a MS Visual Studio feature, a similar feature in Eclipse is called Content Assist. Have you tried pressing Ctrl+Space to force the autocompletion?

Comment: I opened the Content assist windows by pressing Shift+Space, but it showed that there is 'no default proposal'..

Comment: have you opened the Java file with the Java editor? open the file using right button and select the proper editor.